# Kendo-Grid Header for expandable-icon column

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm wondering if I can write something or display something in the header of the "Expand-Icon"-column of my Kendo-Grid in angular. I couldn't find any explanation for this problem in the docs.

[example-grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM4IP.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. My example uses Kendo jQuery but I'm sure it can be done in Angular. The point is once the grid is rendered then you should be able to manipulate the DOM. In this example, the header is a user icon. Try it in the Telerik DOJO.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.301/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.301/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<script id="detail-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <div>
    Name: #: name #
  </div>
  <div>
    Age: #: age #
  </div>
</script>
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" }
  ],
  dataSource: [
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
    { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
  ],
  detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#detail-template").html()),
  dataBound: function(e) {
    let $header = e.sender.element.find('.k-grid-header th.k-hierarchy-cell.k-header');
    $header.append('<span class="k-icon k-i-user"></span>');
  },
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```